# how to make streamwriter create a url link in a non-system folder in C#

Tags: c#, url, shortcut

I am having a problem with creating a url link (shortcut) in a non-system folder. The link is getting created properly on the desktop without any problem, but if I change the path to a non-system folder the folder remains empty and there is no error message either. Is there a restriction on the paths allowed? Why is there no error message?  Code is given below:

```
private void urlShortcutToFolder(string linkName, string linkUrl)
{
    //string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    string nonSystemDir = "C\\Downloads";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nonSystemDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine("URL=" + linkUrl);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as far I know this no proper path:

```
string nonSystemDir = "C\\Downloads";
```

Shouldn't it be

```
string nonSystemDir = "C:\\Downloads";
```

or more readable

```
string nonSystemDir = @"C:\Downloads";
```

You could also add System.IO.Directory.Exists like so

```
private void urlShortcutToFolder(string linkName, string linkUrl)
{
    //string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    string nonSystemDir = @"C:\Downloads";
    if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(nonSystemDir))
    {
        throw New Exception("Path " + nonSystemDir + " is not valid");
    }
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nonSystemDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine("URL=" + linkUrl);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome! Everybody makes them now and them. A break to take my mind of things for a minute or two often helps me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your application locally then your code is right. It must work.
if your application is running oline then you have to set permission  for Internet user on the folder where you want to save your url.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. Its now working on the local machine after correcting the syntax. I need to try it for an internet user. Will update this post at that time.